# LAN->LAN IP translation (for TortoiseSVN + Artifacts + Buffalo router)

Tags: router, port-forwarding, ip-address, tortoisesvn

Here's my scenario:

I've got a VisualSVN server on my main dev box @ home. I'm also using Visual Studio 2010, TortoiseSVN, VisualSVN client (for source control), and Versioned 'Artifacts' (for bug tracking).

(I had to modify the fake URL's below to use only one slash because as a new user, I can't post more than one *real* URL.)

I've got my Buffalo AirStation WHR-HP-G300N router properly configured so my business partner can connect to the SVN server. I have port forwarding enabled for the internet-side IP address (like **http:/99.888.77.66:443**) which gets forwarded to an internal IP (like 192.168.11.6). This part is working great.

The problem I'm having is with the integration piece between TortoiseSVN and my bug tracking system. I need to provide a **bugtraq:url** property, but I haven't been able to get relative paths to work.  So I'm forced to use an absolute URL. On my end, I need to use the *name* of my server (for example: bugtraq:url = **https:/my-server/svn/bla..**), but this doesn't work for my partner.  He needs to specify the IP address (for example: bugtraq:url = **https:/999.888.77.66:443/svn/bla...**)

Is there a way to configure my router such that the IP address for this parameter gets re-routed/re-mapped to "https://my-server" if the request originates from the LAN itself?  My router's software supports LAN->Internet and Internet->LAN, but I don't see LAN->LAN.

Comment: On StackOverflow.com, someone suggested that I try editing the HOSTS file. I tried this, but wasn't able to uncover the magic syntax. Also, I got flaky results when testing different variations. Sometimes my browser would konk out and couldn't resolve addresses until I revert all changes to the HOSTS file.

Comment: Please, we have three IPv4 ranges and one very large IPv6 range for fake addresses. The three IPv4 ranges are `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, `203.0.113.0/24`, and the IPv6 range is `2001:db8::/32`. If you use addresses in these ranges, everybody knows that they are not really what you are using. and the bonus is that you can use the ranges in lab testing of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by someone on StackOverflow.com, the solution was to edit the HOSTS file.  In my case, I needed to get my business partner to edit **his** HOSTS file after I changed the **bugtraq:url** on my end to:

https://my-server/svn/Bla...

Then he modified his HOSTS file as follows:

999.888.77.66    my-server

Works like a charm.